# Should a variable be made for method which is called multiple times?

Tags: java

Here is my method:

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
if(! employees.containsKey(employee.getName())) {
      employees.put(employee.getName(), employee);
  }
}
```

As you see, there is an accessor `employee.getName()` which is called more than once. Should a programmer make a separate variable for such multiple calls? Like this:

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
String name=employee.getName();
if(! employees.containsKey(name)) {
   employees.put(name,employee);
  }
}
```

Does it make sence from the performance point of view, not only style?

Comment: You should use `{}`  around the body of your `if` statement.

Comment: until there is no update.......

Comment: If its a plain getter, it will make no difference from a performance point of view.  I would chose the second example because its cleaner IMHO.

Comment: It is sometimes practical when you debug to see the actual value instead of being forced to `step-into` to be able to get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it make sence from the performance point of view, not only style?

It does if there is lots of calculation included with `getName()`

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense from both the style point of view (it's clearer) and the performance point of view (not doing an operation twice).  As an example, `getName` might require a query to the database, you wouldn't want to do two of those!

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly less verbose.

Performance may be an issue, but I wouldn't optimise *prematurely* for that. You might argue that pulling the variable out in advance would save you from potential performance problems if/when `getName()` was refactored to do something more complex in the future, however. A plain getter won't necessarily remain a plain getter (this is why I advocate unit testing such things - even in a cursory fashion)

However, another issue to consider is **immutability**. Can `employee.getName()` change, and can it be changed by another thread whilst the above is running ? If it can, then your mapping logic will break.

Answer (score 1):

From a style point of view I prefer the first option as I don't think you should introduce local variable unless you are going to change them.

From a performance point of view, I'm not sure there will be a lot a difference, I have no idea what the JIT might be able to do. (In C++ the getter method could be marked as const and the compiler could do the optimization trivially).

Answer (score 0):

Calling a method instead of reading a variable adds a small overhead. If performance is a big issue and that this method is called a lot of times per second, it might make a difference. Otherwise it is a style preference.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If its is called **only once** then assign it to another variable will be useless.

**2.** If its used **more than once** and the **processing of** `getName()` **is huge**, then assigning it to a variable for later use, will be a good idea, as it will save lots of processing time.